# Progress of a make

Tags: bash

I have a Makefile for my LaTeX compilation, however, it outputs A LOT of info. Surely too much to grasp. But, if I leave it out, I'll have trouble finding out why compilations are unsucessful.

I had the idea of creating a progress bar, based on the amount of lines it outputted (assuming I know the total amount of lines it will output)

So basically what I am asking is: Is it possible to dynamically count the amount of lines an execution have outputted?

I'm aware of `wc -l`, but is there any way I can do that mid-way through compilation?

Thanks

Comment: You could have a look at [rubber](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/rubber.1.html). "Rubber  is a wrapper for LaTeX and companion programs.  Its purpose is,
       given a LaTeX source to process, to compile it enough times to  resolve
       all  references,  possibly  running  satellite programs such as BibTeX,
       makeindex, Metapost, etc. to produce appropriate data files."

Comment: @Thomas What does this have to do with showing the progress of the entire compilation?

Comment: Not much, which is why I didn't post it as an answer, but anyone manually writing Makefiles for their LaTeX compilation should at least be aware that there's an easier way :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `pv` utility in line mode:

```
make | pv -l -s EXPECTED_LINES
```

Comment: Thanks @Michal , i didnt know of this before , but is it a standard tool yet ?
@Thomas**About pv** : pv or Pipe viewer  is a terminal-based tool for monitoring the progress of data through a pipeline ,**the home page of pv is(http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml)** 
**example** :
`$ pv access.log | gzip > access.log.gz
611MB 0:00:11 [58.3MB/s] [=>      ] 15% ETA 0:00:59`
**explaination**: 
Pipe viewer acts as "cat" here, except it also adds a progress bar. We can see that gzip processed 611MB of data in 11 seconds. It has processed 15% of all data and it will take 59 more seconds to finish.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply redirecting the standard output to `/dev/null`, leaving just the errors?

```
$ echo info; echo error >&2
info
error
$ (echo info; echo error >&2) > /dev/null
error
```